# How to access individual elements of perl Hashed object?

Tags: perl, infobox

I'm a non-programmer attemting to retrieve useful info from our InfoBlox DHCP boxes. I've installed the Perl API and can make some use of it.

I've got an output from the Data::Dumper "thingie" that appears to have some of the info I want.   I'd like to directly reference some of that data but I'm unsure how.

print Dumper(\$object)

Here is part of the Data::Dumper output;

```
$VAR1 = \bless( {
    'network' => '10.183.1.0/24',
    'override_lease_scavenge_time' => 'false',
    'enable_ifmap_publishing' => 'false',
    'low_water_mark_reset' => '10',
    'use_lease_time' => 0,
    'use_enable_option81' => 0,
    'network_container' => '/',
    'override_ddns_ttl' => 'false',
    'rir' => 'NONE',
    'network_view' => bless( {

<snip> --------------------------------------
    'extattrs' => {
      'Use' => bless( {
        'value' => 'Voip'
      }, 'Infoblox::Grid::Extattr' )
    },
<snip> --------------------------------------
    'members' => [
      bless( {
        'ipv4addr' => '10.85.9.242',
        'name' => 'ig3-app3.my.net'
      }, 'Infoblox::DHCP::Member' ),
      bless( {
        'ipv4addr' => '10.85.9.210',
        'name' => 'ig3-app1.my.net'
      }, 'Infoblox::DHCP::Member' ),
      bless( {
        'ipv4addr' => '10.85.9.226',
        'name' => 'ig3-app2.my.net'
      }, 'Infoblox::DHCP::Member' )
    ],
    'override_ignore_client_identifier' => 'false',
    'email_list' => undef,
    'rir_registration_status' => '??
  }, 'Infoblox::DHCP::Network' );
```

How do I view the elements?   ie ...

```
print $object{members->name};
print $object{members->ipv4addr};

print $object{extattrs->Use->value};
```

I've found the API dox insufficiant for my skill level:)  The data I'd like to pull remains just out of reach.

```
my @retrieved_objs = $session->search (
        object          => "Infoblox::DHCP::Network",
        network         => '.*\.*\.*\..*',

);


        foreach $object ( @retrieved_objs ) {
                my $network = $object->network;
                my $comment = $object->comment;
                my $extattrs    = $object->extattrs;
                my $options = $object->options;
                print $network, " network ", $comment, " ", $extattrs, "  ", $options, "\n";
}
```

-------- output ---

10.183.2.0/24 network  HASH(0x6a2f038)  ARRAY(0x1d20eb0)

10.192.1.0/24 network  HASH(0x9df6540)  ARRAY(0x9df5468)

10.192.2.0/24 network  HASH(0xa088fc8)  ARRAY(0xa089718)

Comment: (`print Dumper($object)` would have made more sense. Dumper dumps scalars, so you'd use `\ ` to dump hashes and arrays, but you don't know to convert scalars into scalars, so you wouldn't use `\ ` for them)

Comment: `$object{members}[0]{name}`, which is short for `$object{members}->[0]->{name}`, but you should be using provided accessors.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't try to access the internal values of an object directly. The module - in this case [`Infoblox::DHCP::Network`](https://ipam.illinois.edu/api/doc/Infoblox/DHCP/Network.html) will provide *methods* that allow you to read or manipulate the values properly.